# How to render a watermark with transparency into a video

Tags: transparency, opacity, watermark, avconv

I'm trying to render a watermark into a video. The moment the image file (.png) for the watermark contains transparency the image isn't rendered into the video anymore. If I convert that image to .jpg and back to .png it works well. If I create a new png that don't have transparency it works too. But when I add e.g. layer opacity to that image it isn't rendered anymore.

I use avconv 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 with the following command

```
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -f 'movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]' -c:v libx264 -t 255 -strict experimental out.mp4
```

If I use .gif for the watermark I get the image, but it's all opaque.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is simple, though it took me a day to find it.

The "normal" ffmpeg that comes with the repository of my Ubuntu distro complained about the "c: v libx264" parameter. avconv knows that parameter but is buggy; it just doesn't render transparent images.

The solution was as simple as installing the very latest ffmpeg version (i choosed the static version). Now it works like a charm. :)

Comment: Yes, ubuntu no longer comes with ffmpeg, but with avconv, which is not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'v managed to add a watermark on a mp4 file (top left) with **avconv** version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2.

```
avconv -y -i source.mp4 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -c:v libx264 target.mp4
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: If you get *Unknown encoder ‘libx264′* error, this is how to solve it.

    apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using *ffmpeg-1.2* rather than avconv then the command is a fairly
simple:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay' -strict -2 outputmovie.mp4
```

This worked fine for me, with the transparency baked into the `logo.png` file. Just make sure there is an alpha there. This also assumes the `logo.png` file is the same size as the reference material.

Answer (score 0):

I Used the transparent png image and it worked for me. Now I can see the scene behind the watermark in the video as the png watermark image is transparent.
So just edit the image via photoshop and add 50%  opacity(or whatever value you want) in the image.